# C++: How to allow own comparison operators()?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm having a custom list class and would like to support operations using the "comparison operator" known from the STL. For example:

```
std::list<MyClass> d;
struct not_key {
    not_key( std::string const& str) : str_(str) {}

    bool operator( MyClass& elem ) {
        return !elem.findThatThing();
    }

    std::string str_;
};


not_key comp("value");
d.remove_if( comp );

mylist<MyClass> e(d);
e.filter( comp );
```

And I'm struggling about the signature of a method which accepts these "general" comparison operators. Since all of them have a different type and I don't want static member functions. How can I add a method to my class which accepts the comparison operators?

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want to know the signature of mylist::filter you would probably just make it a template with Pred or similar as the type.

```
template< typename T >
class mylist
{
   public:
      template< typename Pred >
      void filter( Pred pred )
      {
          // implement, calling pred(elem) for each element or pred(*iter)
      }
};
```

Note that you can pass a free function into that template function, and in C++11 you'll be able to pass in a lambda.

If you want something that isn't a template (other than on the element type) you can use a `boost::function` (or `std::function`)

Comment: ... and if you want the function definition outside of the class (though it should still be in the header file), you need `template<typename T> template<typename Pred> inline void mylist<T>::filter(Pred pred) { /*...*/ }`

Answer (score 3):

The standard functions (such as `std::sort`) use a template argument which is deduced to be the type of your comparison function-like object:

```
template <class UnaryPredicate>
void filter(UnaryPredicate func) {
  // Call it like:
  func(something);
}
```

Now `UnaryPredicate` will be deduced to be the type of whatever function-like object you pass to it. `UnaryPredicate` makes more sense than calling it a comparison function since it only takes a single argument. A comparison function would typically take two arguments and compare them.

Alternatively, you could take a `std::function<bool(const MyClass&)>`:

```
void filter(std::function<bool(const MyClass&)> func) {
  // Call it like:
  func(something);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature should be:

```
bool operator()(Myclass const & elem) const
```

Comment: Probably true, but not an answer.